# matplotlib is not showing output in simple tutorial program

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, tkinter

```
import numpy as np
import  cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

img = cv2.imread('flood.jpg',0)
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Above is my code and when I run this program Ii get

```
"/home/badal/Python-3.7.1/image_process/im2.py:9: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
 plt.show()
```

After using tkagg I get

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/badal/Python-3.7.1/image_process/im2.py", line 5, in 
> import tkinter as tk
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 36, in 
> import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'"

```
import numpy as np
import  cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import tkinter as tk
matplotlib.use('tkagg')

img = cv2.imread('flood.jpg',0)
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

I have already installed tkinter, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: To read in an image using OpenCV you can do `image = cv2.imread('image.png')`. To display it, you can do `cv2.imshow('image', image)` with `cv2.waitKey()`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is on cv2 module that I don't know what is.

```
img = cv2.imread('flood.jpg',0)
```

However I made some changes.

First of all I don't import cv2 module.

Second I import Image from PIL.

And to open the pic I made

```
img = Image.open('flood.jpg')
```

So your code becomes:

```
import numpy as np
#import  cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('flood.jpg')
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: i get :
    /home/badal/Python-3.7.1/image_process/im2.py:10: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()
error after using  the abov code that you have written for me.

Comment: I don't know, try to read  https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/introductory/usage.html  where talk about Backends. I'm , on Debian.